# Access custom key in JSON

Tags: json

I seem to not be able to remember how to access a randomly generated key in my JSON file.

it looks like this:

```
  fb: {
"735175xxxx299879547_19953232xxxxx": {
  urlTarget:
    "xxxx,
  name: "xxxx",
```

I want to access 'form.fb.7351...' but if it's randomly generated each time.. how would I do so? I can't seem to figure it out at all.

Thanks

Comment: If you know it's the only key that will appear in that position you don't need the name. Otherwise you could maybe give it a common prefix or something, so you can recognize it that way.

Comment: And how would you access it then, if it's the only key to appear? :)

Comment: You'll have to parse the JSON. The implementation depends on the programming language you are using, you haven't told us which language this is. jtate's answer applies if you're using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like A Boschman said, if it's always the first property of your object, you can retrieve it using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var keys = Object.keys(fb);
var value = fb[keys[0]];
```